# Fade and slide animatable elements on window scroll

Tags: javascript, performance, css, animation

I wrote a simple JavaScript function to animate objects on my webpage to fade and slide in from the bottom of the screen when the user scrolls them into view.  I did this by using JavaScript to add and remove a CSS class that animates the element to every element with the `showOnScroll` class.

Example element:

```
<content-card class="animated showOnScroll" data="[[item]]"></content-card>
```

JavaScript function:

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var toShow =  document.querySelectorAll('.showOnScroll');
  for(var i = 0; i < toShow.length; i++) {
    if(window.innerHeight - toShow[i].getBoundingClientRect().top - 100 > 0) {
      toShow[i].classList.remove('fadeOutDown');
      toShow[i].classList.add('fadeInUp');
    } else {
      toShow[i].classList.remove('fadeInUp');
      toShow[i].classList.add('fadeOutDown');
    }
  }
}
```

The `fadeInUp` and `fadeInDown` classes use CSS to animate the elements.  See a work in progress [here](http://beta.intcreator.com/) (may not work on mobile).  The app is written using Polymer.

I'm mostly concerned about performance—if I have around 50 of these elements on a page, can that noticeably impact most browsers?  If so, I have a couple of ideas to optimize already:

- Remove the `showOnScroll` class once an element has been scrolled in (only animate each element once instead of fading in and out)
- Append elements to the DOM as the user scrolls down
- Only run the loop if the user scrolls at least 50px

Are these going in the right direction?  Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: Short answer: attaching things to the `scroll` event can be a recipe for disaster. (Especially when touching the DOM.) You should look into throttling your function (and also move things like `var toShow =  document.querySelectorAll('.showOnScroll');` outside the scroll listener).